# Gparted cannot resize extended or LVM partition

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, gparted, lvm

I created a VM using VirtualBox and realized it was too small. After some time I managed to create a new, bigger hard drive.

Live GParted CD image (v.022):

[image: GParted screenshot]

Now I need to integrate the unallocated space to the `/dev/sda5` partition.

- Right-clicking on sda5 shows the option to resize but I dont get any free space before or after.
- I though that perhaps I needed to extend the sda2 partition first but right-clicking on sda2 does not allow me to resize.

Do you have any useful advice?

Comment: this image sourced from the linux HOST or GUEST (aka VM)

Comment: The image is from the guest VM, sorry if I was not clear

Comment: Okay ,  Is the vg crypted OR just mounted   in both cases it needs to be unmounted and additionally in the first case  decrypted  and unmounted

Comment: It is not encrypted. Since I started from the gparted live cd, shouldn't all partitions be unmounted? If not, how do I unmount them from gparted?

Comment: the lock implies mounted or crypted  select them  should have ` unmount ` option

Comment: The lock you mentioned was the problem. There was a choice called deactivate, I used it, increased the extended partition (sda2) and then increased the lvm partition (sda5). It worked fine. Still, when I enter my VM I see only the previous space as available, but I suspect I must do something to increase th filesystem in the, now allocated, space.

Comment: lvextend -r  /dev/sda5   should fix that  (the -r  'flag' tells the system to resize the filesystem as well)

Comment: Yes, I already found out, after your help, and wrote something similar in the answer

Answer (score 65, accepted):

After some help from [linuxdev2013](https://superuser.com/users/295176/linuxdev2013), this is what I did:
The problem was that the partitions were somehow locked. So:

1. I right Clicked both sda2 and sda5 and chose "Deactivate".
2. I resized the extended (sda2) partition.
3. I resized the lvm (sda5) partition.

The problem was fixed.

I should add that in the VM the new space was not available, so I had to run those 2 commands:
    expand LVM to all remaining free space:

```
lvextend –l +100%FREE [MOUNTPOINT]
```

expand filesystem:

```
sudo resize2fs [MOUNTPOINT]
```

Comment: Thanks! I also needed lvm lvdisplay to get the exact device for lvextend, and later df -h to find out the volume on which to resize.

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer, that saved me hours and grey hair!

Comment: After using gparted, the partition wasn't showing the right amount free. These 2 command line functions were exactly what I needed to finish the job. Thanks for sharing that wizardry

Comment: Unfortunately, for me deactivating them doesn't work. No error message either... Any hints?

Comment: I had to run `sudo lvdisplay` to get the [MOUNTPOINT]. In my case it came back as LV Path (/dev/ubuntu-vg/root)

Comment: Nothing was working for me, the lock wouldn't go away even after trying to "deactivate" several times. The only thing that actually unlocked my partition in gparted was to create a new partition in the empty space and then delete it. The lock icon went away and I was able to extend the extended partition...

Comment: The GParted Live CD image automatically used the swap space within the LVM partition of my RHEL 5 and 6 VMs.  I had to run `sudo swapoff -a` from the command line then use the `deactivate` on the partitions with the padlock.

Comment: Thanks - The deactivate of the extended and VG partitions did it for me.

Comment: This helped me realize that I had to extend sda2 AND sda5 (using the example image above). 
I was pulling my hair out as to why I didn't seem to have any room to extend sda5, even when booting from a liveCD

Comment: the argument for `lvextend` would be capital `-L` instead of `-l` if using actual size like 1GB. For swap, do `swapoff -a` then `sudo mkswap [MOUNTPOINT]` then `swapon -a`

Answer (score 2):

appliance@zabbix:~$ **sudo lvdisplay**

--- Logical volume ---

LV Path                /dev/zabbix-vg/root

LV Name                root

VG Name                zabbix-vg

LV Size                **15.52 GiB**

--- Logical volume ---

LV Path                /dev/zabbix-vg/swap_1

LV Name                swap_1

VG Name                zabbix-vg

LV Size                4.00 GiB

appliance@zabbix:~$ **sudo vgs**

VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree

zabbix-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 24.52g 5.00g

As you see i have **5 GB Free space**

appliance@zabbix:~$ **sudo lvextend -L+5G /dev/zabbix-vg/root**

Size of logical volume zabbix-vg/root changed from 15.52 GiB (3973 extents) to 20.52 GiB (5253 extents).

Logical volume root successfully resized.

appliance@zabbix:~$ **sudo resize2fs /dev/zabbix-vg/root**

The filesystem on /dev/zabbix-vg/root is now 5379072 (4k) blocks long.

appliance@zabbix:~$ **sudo lvdisplay**

--- Logical volume ---

LV Path                /dev/zabbix-vg/root

LV Name                root

VG Name                zabbix-vg

LV Size                **20.52 GiB**

--- Logical volume ---

LV Path                /dev/zabbix-vg/swap_1

LV Name                swap_1

VG Name                zabbix-vg

LV Size                4.00 GiB

Comment: He was asking how to resize the physical volume ( the disk partition ), not a logical volume.

Comment: exactly what I am looking for. extended my physical drive with no problem but it doesn't apply on the logical drive. you helped me adjust my logical drive. thanks a million!