# Cannot increase file size for .VDI file

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to increase my .VDI file hard disk.

I'm following instructions from http://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/ and have come up with an issue.

I've increased the hard drive via VBoxManage commands, as per this screen shot

[image]

I'm now told to boot into a GParted Live CD. I've downloaded the .iso but when I boot, I am supposed to see a hard drive with both allocated and unallocated space, as per this screen shot on the link above

[image]

What I see is
[image]

I seem to have a tree view. I don't understand why this is. I also can right click on both /dev/sda2 and but have no option to resize! If I right click on /dev/sda5  then I can resize but it's already the maximum width.

The hard drive I want to expand is sda5, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled sda5 and then was able to resize sda2 and everything just... worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer's in the used file sizes. You have a lvm volume that's nearly full right after sda2. You need *continuous* free space  to resize and you really couldn't shrink sda5 (since its full) to extend sda2.

As you found out, you need to deactivate a pv to resize it though I wonder if [pvresize](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98374/27961) would work.  The comments thread [here seems to suggest](https://superuser.com/a/918346/10165) its a quirk of using gparted and a livecd together.